# WebViewのDownloadListenerについて

Tags: android, java, webview

android5.0以降でDownloadListenerが呼ばれないのですが原因は何でしょうか？
何か対策はありますでしょうか？

Gmailの添付ファイルをクリックした時だけ呼ばれていないみたいです。

Answer (score 1):

onDownloadListener というインターフェースはないので、そこが間違っていると思います。